# Error while running the Ant Build File

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to run the ant build file I generated from the Eclipse using the steps :

1. Right Click on Project, then "Export"
2. Under General -> Ant Build File

But When I try to do Run As -> Ant Build File, It shows the following error:

Class not found: org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the 1st solution  [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t14808.html) this should do